# Ejecutar un script para MySQL con powershell

Tags: mysql, sql, powershell

Estoy estoy tratando de ejecutar un script (database.sql) para MySQL. Este archivo tiene todas las querys de una database, y necesito ejecutarlo con powershell para que me genere una base de datos con todo lo que tenga el archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar este archivo en powershell?

Comment: No das detalles del problema. No indicas que SGBD estas usando (MySQL, Oracle, etc.).

Comment: Estoy utilizando mysql

Comment: Es decir quieres generar tu base de datos a partir de ese respaldo?

Comment: Si asi es, quiero ejecutar este sql para que sus querys generen mi DB

Answer (score 0):

Acá el comando, donde se debe de instanciar la bd, el usuario, la contraseña, etc.

```
OSQL -U [usuario] -P [contraseña] -S [server]\SQLEXPRESS(instancia SQL) -i C:\myScript.sql(colocas la ubicación del script y listo)
```

Comment: Si pero es mysql no SQL SERVER, de todas formas gracias por la data

Answer (score 0):

El comando para importar un respaldo a una base de datos MySQL sería:

```
mysql -u miusuario -p mibasededatos < archivo.sql
```

Lo uso en la terminal de xampp en windows 10 y funciona.